# Отключение прокрутки slick

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

Может есть какое-либо свойство или решение, чтобы при использовании стрелок нижнего слайдера верхний оставался статичным?Необходимо чтобы верхний слайдер менял current slide, но сам слайдер не сдвигался.
https://simadmtr.github.io/FonoMono/payment.html

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Comment: Это у вас 2 разных слайдера?(slick) Вы их инициализируете по отдельности? Предоставьте примеры...